# What is the correct way to access Vuex getters from Cypress?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, cypress

I have a getter called `viewItems` in my Vuex store, returning an array.
I can access it from my Cypress test with:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getStore", () => {
  return cy.window().its("app.$store");
});

cy.getStore().its("getters.viewItems.length").should("equal", 13);
```

It works, but I get an error on the console when running Cypress:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "nodeType" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties
```

Is there a better way to access getters, or is it something else?

Comment: Not sure it will help, but the developers of our project had made a `store.login` dispatch command and helped me devise this code. `cy.window()
        .then(window => {
            cy.wrap(
                window.$nuxt.$store.dispatch('login', {
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.password,
                })
            )
        })`  We are developing a VUE app and it doesn`t get this error, though I had seen it in the compiler before and maybe it will help u

Comment: Can you try directly comparing the length: `cy.getStore().its("getters.viewItems").should('have.length',13)`?

Comment: @Otto Paulsen, without this test the error disappears? it seems to me that the error is not in the test.